# Sleeping queries and slowness of MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a software application built with Electron, there is an Ajax call every seconds.
Everything seems to work however the server gets smashed and we are experiencing massive overload, slowness. The sites would be fast, then slow, and suddently fast again or sometimes keeps spinning. We have 8 users using the application which result to 80 queries per seconds.

Here my cnf file

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
max_allowed_packet = 64M
max_user_connections = 100
max_delayed_threads = 0
tmpdir = /tmp
wait_timeout = 300
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam-recover-options = DEFAULT
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/
innodb_log_file_size = 16M
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
table_definition_cache = 8192
table_open_cache = 16384
log-error = /var/log/mysql.error.log
log-warnings = 3

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 32M

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

!include /etc/my.cnf.d/hwconf.conf
```

I'm notb sure and have no clue of what i can do to avoid this, i spoke to the hosting and they say that there is some sleeping queries sometimes, not much help there.

Comment: How do you know that the slowness of the site is caused by mysql? Have you looked at replacing polling bevery second with slternative solutions or at least reducing the interval? What do you expect from us from a programming point of view (remember, this is SO, not the DBA Q/A site!)?

Comment: 8 users using the site with an ajax request every second for every user is 8 queries per second, not 80. Quick Mafs

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance improving suggestions.

Comment: What queries do you run 80 times a second?  One simple query is no problem.  Multiple complex queries will bog down the server.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  How much data in the database?  (`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M` may be too small.)

Answer (score 0):

Things to do in order:

1. Check the process list using SHOW PROCESSLIST, see what's slow, maybe it's something obvious. If it's slow you'll see the query.
2. Check the slow query log.
3. Use a tool like Percona Toolkit or JetProfiler to zoom in on any problem not obvious from 1 or 2.